# How to return a string without quotes in a function?

Tags: python, function, return

This is a part of my code:

```
def LeapYear(year=0,month=0,day=0):
 .
 .
 .
  # as it's a long code I've jumped the unnecessary things.
 .
 .
 .    
return ("Today is the {}th day of the year!".format(T))
```

It returns the string like this (with quotes):

```
'Today is the 70th day of the year!'
```

But I want it to be returned like this (without quotes):

```
Today is the 70th day of the year!
```

I don't want to use a function for doing this and as I have many of such lines I don't want the solution to be long, Is there a way?

Comment: The quotes are not part of the string. If you `print` it, the quotes will not appear.

Comment: What do you mean by without quotes? It's a string, and string are always represented with "quotes" in python. Could u describe what are you trying to do here?

Comment: You can only see the string if you print it; the single quotes are *not* part of the returned value; they are added by `str.__repr__` when a representation of the value needs to be shown in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: @Moty.R  `It's python syntax`. Plus why would you want a lengthy string returned, print the year & return the year as `Int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it **returns** the string with quotes because that's how strings are represented. However, if you **print** it, for example `print(LeapYear)` will print it normally, `Today is the 70th day of the year!`.

Another example is this: how would you make define a string variable? It's like this:

```
string = 'Example String'
```

and not this:

```
string = Example String
```

And if you do

```
print(string)
```

it will print `Example String`, without the quotes.